# Is it possible to download Azure Spatial Anchor(and feature points) for offline alignment in Unity?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I would like to ask if it's possible to download the Azure Spatial Anchor (and the feature points) and load it into Unity so that we can align the hologram/virtual objects to the anchor offline in Unity. I think this support is extremely important for application developers. If it's not possible now, is there any workaround, and is it one of the road-map item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@marklinmao,There is no option to export the feature points out of the sdk today. We are collecting suggestions and feedback for future improvements please feel free to add an item here for us to consider it in the future.

You can leave your feedback here:[Azure Spatial Anchors Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I will add it to the feedback list.